# QXMLStreamReader cannot read attribute

Tags: c++, xml, qt, xsd, qxmlstreamreader

I want to parse the following xml (it's a xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name = "elementName">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base = "xs:string">
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

At some point I invoke following method, that should read the `base` attribute of `restriction`:

```
void String::getFromBase() const {
  QXMLStreamReader m_node; // in true code it's a class member already initialized
  m_node.readNextStartElement();
  auto name = stripNamespace(m_node.name().toString()); // convert xs:restriction to restriction
  if (name != "restriction") {
    throw Exception("Restriction is not found when reading string data");
  }
  bool hasBase{false};
  auto x = m_node.attributes().size(); // x is zero but it should be one
  for (const auto& it : m_node.attributes()) {
    auto attrName = stripNamespace(it.name().toString());
    if (attrName == "base") {
      hasBase = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!hasBase) {
    throw Exception("Restriction needs 'base' attribute");
  }
  auto attribute = stripNamespace(m_node.attributes().value(BaseLabel).toString());
  if (attribute == "string") {
    int i = 0;
  }
}
```

The method checks that the actual element in `QXMLStreamReader` is `restriction`, and this check passes, but then the size of `attributes()` is zero, so the reader does not find any attribute. Since I've only one `restriction` in my testing XSD, attributes should be there. How can I read the `base` attribute value correctly?

Comment: What technical task is your program performing (i.e. why are you parsing the XSD as an XML file)?

Comment: For creating a custom gui for creating XML files that satisfy the xsd.

Comment: This line looks suspicious: "if (name != restriction) {" I would have expected quotes around 'restriction' (unless you have a local variable with name 'restriction' and value "restriction").

Comment: Yes there are quotes it's a typo..